# About the theorem of Weierstrass?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, polynomials, teaching

> 1. Is $E=Vect\{1,x,x^2,...,x^{2^n},...\}$ dense in $C([0,1])$ for the uniform norm?

While looking for a short proof for Weierstrass' theorem, I came across this justification(*) (which shows this result) but which it turns out to be false.

(*) : https://forum.prepas.org/viewtopic.php?t=76646&start=20#p1028993

> 2. Do you know a short proof of Weierstrass' theorem, starting from level L2?

Comment: What is “Level L2”?

Comment: Level second year of license

Comment: I see, a less France-specific way of saying this is “(second/third-year) undergraduate student”.

Comment: Your notation means, $E$ is the vector space generated by $1$ and all functions of the form $x^{2^n}$, $n=0,1,2,\dots$?

Comment: The Müntz theorem says that the linear span of $1$, $x^{p_1}$, $x^{p_2}$, etc. is dense in $C[0,1]$ if and only if $\sum_n 1/p_n=\infty$. This answers Question 1 in the negative.

Comment: I learned the approximation by the Bernstein_polynomials in my second year of the university -- see e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernstein_polynomial#Probabilistic_proof; also, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernstein_polynomial#Elementary_proof

Comment: An elementary proof of the Stone-Weierstrass theorem is given in https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1981-081-01/S0002-9939-1981-0589143-8/S0002-9939-1981-0589143-8.pdf

Comment: Lebesgue's proof is also very short and elementary. See e.g. the "report" at https://apps.dtic.mil/sti/citations/ADA118974 , which presents "this proof [...] suitable for undergraduate mathematics majors" in excruciating detail.